# Azure WebJob Publishing Issue

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a solution that contains some Azure WebJobs and I have a weird issue when i go to publish them. I wanted to see if anyone ever experienced this or might know what I'm overlooking as this is just annoying.

When I go to publish the WebJob after something was changed it always fails. The steps to get it published is as follows.

1. Attempt to publish and let it fail.
2. Delete the publish profiles, I have 2 because of the next 2 steps.
3. Re-import the publish profile and attempt to publish again, it will fail.
4. Re-import the publish profile a second time, this will make it with a (2) in the name. Publish again and this time it will publish correctly.

If I do not follow these steps I cannot get the job to publish without an error. I've tried every combination and looked at all the settings and solution files but cannot find a reason for this. This started a few months ago and I'm not sure what the cause is. These jobs are not something that get updated very often so I only have to go through this every 4-6 weeks so I have not been too concerned with it. But I wanted to see if anyone might know anything that might cause this as I would love to get it back to publishing like it should.

Comment: You could publish without importing Profile, you could choose Microsoft Azure App Service while you "Select a publish target" , then choose your group and web app. And you must Validate Connection whichever  way you use.

Comment: You need make sure your connection is ok then Publish you job.